# Why browser becomes slow with large number o DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, browser

I know this question sounds very trivial, but I just want to know how 'browser processes DOM and what makes it become slow with large number of DOM elements? Is this just about the size? What if DOM elements are not high in number but javascript objects are? Would it still respond slow?

I guess, if there are events attached to javascript objects and we don't dispose them, it responds slow because it has to execute all the event handlers (in a sequential manner), but other than that what are the other reason where 'memory leak' slows down the browser? (Assuming browser has consumed lots of memory but enough memory is still usable in system).

Update:
Surprisingly, CPU and memory usage is always under control while browser responds slow.

Comment: Do you mean about ***FireFox***? At least that's the worst one when it comes to memory issue.

Comment: It's not a "memory leak" if a large amount of memory is required due to having a large amount of data.

Comment: @nnnnnn, fine, it is not a memory leak, but can it impact on browser perfromance.

Answer (score 0):

If a page is loaded with all its elements and it doesn't change, then there is no reason why it should be slow no matter the amount of DOM elements. However, if you have a dynamic page, there are loads of operations that cause the entire layout to redraw itself. This is called [layout thrashing](http://kellegous.com/j/2013/01/26/layout-performance/) and can have dramatic effects on performance.

Comment: it becomes slow after everything is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious is that your browser consumps all your memory and when it comes time to render something during scrolling, for example it has no more memory.
If there are no memory issues, then JohanP is write - there is no reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Why do browsers slow down when loading a lot of data? Because they have to load a lot of data. Large images are obviously the worst culprit in terms of load speed, but page load is directly correlated to the number of kilobytes being transmitted. If you have a lot of code, it's going to have a large filesize.

As for JavaScript, there are four main causes of leaks:

1. **Accidental Global Variables** -- Variables not explicitly defined will assume a global scope:

   `function foo(arg) {
     bar = "This is a global variable";
   }`
2. **Forgotten Timers Or Callbacks** -- When declaring a variable in a timed function like `setInterval(function() {})`, the variable still exists at the end of the interval.
3. **Out Of DOM References** -- When assigning reference to an element, which later is removed, the reference still exists:

   `var button: document.getElementById('button');
   document.body.removeChild(document.getElementById('button'));`
4. **Closures** -- Loops often don't get closed 'correctly', losing variable scope, and leaking in the process. See **[JavaScript closures](http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-closures-with-ease/)**.

See **[4 Types of Memory Leaks in JavaScript and How to Get Rid Of Them](https://auth0.com/blog/four-types-of-leaks-in-your-javascript-code-and-how-to-get-rid-of-them/)** for further information on JavaScript memory leaks.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I am not talking about 'load time'. Once it is loaded, it responds slow on user's actions. Lets say, scrolling becomes sluggish, opening a drop-down starts taking time and so on.

Comment: *"2. ...the variable still exists at the end of the interval."* - no it doesn't. Why would it? setInterval calls your function, your function runs to completion, local variables not kept. Unless there was a nested function causing a closure situation or objects were created that are referenced outside the function, neither of which are inherent problems with setInterval.